# Azure AD App Registration: "AADSTS90094: The grant requires admin permission" error for permission that has "REQUIRES ADMIN" set to "No"

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am setting up an App Registration in the Azure AD portal to be used with my sample ASP.Net Core 2 web app. For starters, I want to get basic authentication working. I am configuring this app to enable only one permission, "Sign in and read user profile", note that it *does not* require admin permission:

[image: AD App Registration, Enable Access blade]

However, when I run my web app and attempt to authenticate against this client ID, I get the "AADSTS90094: The grant requires admin permission" error:

> You can't access this application
>
> AspNetCoreAdAuth needs permission to access resources in your
>   organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to
>   grant permission to this app before you can use it.

This is the URL that my app uses to authenticate (with some sensitive or irrelevant data removed):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my_tenant_id>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<my_client_id>&redirect_uri=<my_redirect_uri>&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=<gibberish>&state=<giberrish>&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=2.1.4.0
```

Majority of solutions on SO and elsewhere propose to simply use the "Grant Permissions" button to get past this error. However

- As a developer I don't have admin rights
- Asking an admin to grant this permission for everyone seems like a sledgehammer approach
- I'd like to understand why this is happening or what am I doing wrong that causes this to not work the way it seems it should work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible reason is that your organisation administrator has disabled the **Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf** setting.

You can find it under *User settings*:

[image: User settings]